# Can Laravel using join table to get data?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Just some random thought, can laravel using join table rather than using eloquent relationship. Because most of answers that i read in here suggest to using relationship like belongstoMany, belongsto and other eloquent relationship. If can, it should be nice if u guys giving me some sample code about how to do that. Sorry for the silly question. Thank you

Comment: What kind of functionality are you missing with eloquent relationships?

Comment: Yes you can use joins. Relationships are better though.

Comment: You better study  the document : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic example using something I created a while ago using joins which were a forum thread table and a forum replies table. See below:

```
$forum = Forum::where('forumType', '=', $topic->forumType)
    ->leftJoin('forum_replies','forum_topics.forumid','=','forum_replies.topic_id')
    ->groupBy('forum_topics.forumid')
    ->orderBy('forum_replies.updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

The above examples joins the `forumid` from forum_topics table to the forum_replies table's `topic_id`

Not a very tidy way of doing it though, you should definitely approach this by using relationships instead.

The code above was converted some time ago to relationships instead of using joins.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the join as per your requirement if you don't want to add relationship like this

```
user::select('in_user_id', 'st_first_name', 'st_last_name', 
'in_contact_no', 'email', 'tbl_city.st_city_name', 
'tbl_usertype_master.st_usertype_name', 'tbl_center.st_center_name', 
'is_active')->leftjoin('tbl_city', 'tbl_city.in_city_id', 
'tbl_user.in_city_id')-> 
leftjoin('tbl_usertype_master','tbl_usertype_master.in_usertype_id', 
'tbl_user.in_usertype_id')->leftjoin('tbl_center', 
'tbl_center.in_center_id', 'tbl_user.in_center_id');
```

in this manner you can use join in laravel here i use for display user from User table

Hope this helps you

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel query builder supports almost all SQL sentences, you can see all available methods here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries